# how could explain mb-xl-5 for div in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

I know mb-1, mb-2 or xl-1, xl-2 but how could explain mb-xl-5 for div. mb-2 means margin-bottom 0.5 and xl means extra-large but what is means mb-xl-2

Answer (score 1):

according to naming convention it shows **mb- margin bottom** which has several levels such as xs,sm,md,xl so **in this case its xl** and each level has certain default sizes in each for the following -1,-2,-3 with corresponding pixels set by default by the package.

for ex.
mb-xl-2
margin bottom for extra large (with default 20px) and - 2 maybe its a multiple that is 40px.

note : these values depends on the package

Comment: default 20px, for what? for margin-bottom or for extra large

Comment: extra large.. default value might be 20px               ...1 - 20px ,2-40px 3- 60px like that